# RSS Error utf-8 wordpress

Tags: wordpress, rss

I get the following error when i try to open the RSS Feed of the customer page:

"This page contains the following errors:

error on line 742 at column 28: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0x1B 0x1B 0x3C 0x61
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."

How can i fix this error? 
Thanks!

The pages url is: [WEBSITE LINK](http://vietnam-cooking-experience.com)

Comment: There is no feed address in your page. Check this link about your [link](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fvietnam-cooking-experience.com%2F)

Comment: how can i get one? at the moment it should be http://vietnam-cooking-experience.com/feed/

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress handles that for you. In case you are not using it, add these lines to you header:

```
<head>
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Vietnam Cooking" href="http://vietnam-cooking-experience.com/feed/" />
  <link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" title="RSS .92" href="http://vietnam-cooking-experience.com/feed/rss/" />
  ...
</head>
```

But still, RSS feeds must be generated correctly.